# Wrong predicate-logic translation?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

> A set $S$ of whole numbers is called **stapled** if and only if for every whole number $a$ which is in $S$ there exists a prime factor of $a$ which divides at least one other number in $S.$

> Let $T$ be a set of whole numbers. Which of the following is true if and only if $T$ is not stapled?

Taking the domain as all the whole numbers in the set, $S$ is stapled iff

$\forall a \exists b$(there exists a prime factor in $a$ which divides $b$).

Taking the negation:

$\exists a \forall b$(there does not exist a prime factor in $a$ which divides $b$).

In normal words:

There exists a whole number $a$ where there does not exist a prime factor in $a$ which divides all $b.$

So my answer would be:

> There exists an number $a$ which is in $T$ such that there is no prime factor of $a$ which divides every other number in $T.$

However, the correct answer is:

> There exists a number a which is in $T$ such that there is no prime factor of $a$ which divides at least one other number in $T.$

What went wrong in my solution?

Comment: The "logical form is: $\forall a \in T \exists k \exists b \in T[b \ne a \land k|a \land k|b]$  When you negate the statement you "switch" the initial quantifier from $\forall a$ to $\exists a$ and you have $\exists a \lnot \exists k (\ldots)$. If you stop there, without moving further inside the negation sign, the statement will be: "There exists a number a in T such that there is **no** ..." and what follows is unchanged: "prime factor of a which divides at least one other number in T".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **GIVEN DEFINITION**: A set S of whole numbers is called **stapled** if and only if for every whole number $a$ which is in $S$ there exists a prime factor of $a$ which divides at least one other number in $S.$
>
> Taking the domain as all the whole numbers in the set, $S$ is stapled iff
>
> $\quad\forall a \exists b$(there exists a prime factor of $a$ which divides $b$).

You neglected to account for the word "other" in the given definition. A correct translation (where $\mathbb P$ denotes the set of prime numbers) is:

$$\forall a\in S \;\;\exists p\in\mathbb P \;\;\exists b\in S \;( p|a \;\text{and}\; p|b \;\text{and}\; a \neq b)\tag#$$

> Taking the negation:
>
> $\quad \exists a \forall b$(there does not exist a prime factor in $a$ which divides $b$).
>
> $\quad$There exists a whole number $a$ where there does not exist a prime factor in $a$ which divides all $b.$

Your natural-language translation of your symbolic negation is wrong; it ought to be instead be (note that the placement of **every/all $b$** is crucial because the meaning of the sentence varies according to that): "There exists a whole number $a$ such that **for each $b,$** there does not exist a prime factor in $a$ which divides $b.$"

> **GIVEN EXERCISE**: Let T be a set of whole numbers. Which of the
> following is true if and only if T is not stapled?
>
> However, the correct answer is: "There exists a number a which is in T
> such that there is no prime factor of a which divides at least one
> other number in T."

This is correct, because it does correspond to the negation of $(\#):$ $$\exists a\in S \;\;\not\exists p\in\mathbb P \;\;\exists b\in S \;( p|a \;\text{and}\; p|b \;\text{and}\; a \neq b).$$ An equivalent negation of $(\#):$ $$\exists a\in T \;\;\forall p\in\mathbb P \;\;\forall b\in T \;( p\not|a \;\text{or}\; p\not|b \;\text{or}\; a = b).$$